# Android/Phonegap - Weird thin line at bottom of scrollable DIV

Tags: android, cordova

Very simple problem. I have a Div, with a fixed height and:

overflow: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;

In that div I display a Table which is like 500 TR rows in length and needs to be scrolled in order to see all its content. When displayed on an Android (4.2.2) device, a thin line appears at the bottom of the Table (or more probably the Div).

When I scroll down the entire Div (when the scroll thumb is at the bottom), it disappears. Here's a picture:

http://www.arnoldmcdonald.org/temp/Untitled.png

What is it (looks like a "hint" to tell the user that the table is scrollable) and, more importantly, how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

not a hint, it's a bug.

I get rid of it by setting margin: -1px (means minus one px)

the line is the original background black color when 2 div next to each other.  it only comes out on some Android versions.

Comment: I have no other div above or below, so it can't be that. Besides, it only appears when the div is has a scroll bar. And when you scroll the div fully, when you reach the end of its content, it disappears. Therefore, it's by design. Last, I tried your tip and it does not work.Thanks anyway.

Comment: We have very similar case, I think it's not by design, because if I do not scroll down the div, the line does not appear too!

Comment: You may try to add Another 'empty' or 'Very short' div with margin = -1px after your div to see if it will disappear or not